# POJO getter returning JPQL query result?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, pojo

I'm sorry if this is a poor question, but I was wondering if it's ok for a POJO to have a getter returning an JPQL query result? 
Would it be a better practice to make the assignment in the constructor?

```
public Long getCount() {
 Long count = 0L;
    if (date != null) {
        count = (Long) entityManager.createNamedQuery(query)
                .setParameter(1, someCriteria.getId())
                .setParameter(2, someDate)
                .getSingleResult();
    } else {
        count = (Long) entityManager.createNamedQuery(query)
                .setParameter(1, someCriteria.getId())
                .getSingleResult();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I think that having dependencies to repository/service in your model is a poor design in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, generally speaking I personally think is not a bad practice to have even complex operation performed by getters method. This has to do with information hiding and complexity hiding. The caller just invoke “getThat()” and the complexity behind the operation is completely hidden to the callers.

Different considerations are  performance and efficiency. If the operation performed by the getter is expensive, you should think to some optimization policy. Depending on the circumstances you can store the result in a local variable, a local DB, or apply other kind of policies to avoid to recalculate the result every time the getter is called. All depends on the meaning of the result, on the speed the result would change and on the importance for the application to get the up to date value.

Comment: I don't have a clear understanding of an exact definition of a POJO. But I'd expect an object called a POJO (depending on the context) to be a simple business object. I would expect a getter in such an object to return a value available in its instance variables (or derived thereof) but not to execute a call to the persistence layer. I'd put this code into a finder method on a data access object just to avoid surprising another developer (something I consider a code smell).